# ¿Cómo cambiar color de elementos HTML según su Clase desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero cambiar la propiedad color de los elementos de Clase 'hS1' pero solo cambia el color de fondo. Este sería el JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function () { 
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#4B4443';
  document.getElementsByClassName('hS1').style.color = '#EFEFEF';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` de devuelve una especie de array de elementos (llamado [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)), NO un solo elemento. Fíjate que dice `elementSSSS`

Este pseudo array no tiene la propiedad `style`, está propiedad pertenece a UN elemento en particular.

En otras palabras, ya que tienes una colección, tienes que hacer un `for`

```
let elementos =document.getElementsByClassName('hS1');
for(let i=0; i<elementos.length;i++){
   elementos[i].style.color = '#EFEFEF'
}
```

O usando `queryselectorAll` es mas corto

```
document.querySelectorAll(".hs1").forEach(a=>a.style.color = '#EFEFEF');
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la [**documentación**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

> Retorna un objeto similar a un array de los elementos hijos que tengan todos los nombres de clase indicados. Cuando es llamado sobre el objeto document , la busqueda se realiza en todo el document, incluido el nodo raíz.

En pocas palabras, `getElementsByClassName()` devuelve una lista de elementos, incluso si solo hay un elemento con la clase que especifiques. Entonces, la solución sería iterar sobre la lista y aplicar el estilo a cada elemento con la clase `hS1` individualmente, usando el ciclo `for`:

```
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function () { 
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#4B4443';
  let elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('hS1');
  for (let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    elementos[i].style.color = '#EFEFEF';
  }
});
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function () { 
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#4B4443';
  let elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('hS1');
  for (let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    elementos[i].style.color = '#EFEFEF';
  }
});
```

```html
<h5 class="hS1">Título</h5>
<h5 class="hS1">Título</h5>
<h5 class="hS1">Título</h5>
<button id="btn1">Cambiar estilo</button>
```